# RESTful webservice hosted on iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, rest

My question is, Is there a way to host RESTful webservice on iPhone? This is possible in java based mobile.

[RESTful Web Services Implementations in Mobile Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452670/restful-web-services-implementations-in-mobile-devices)

EDIT:
I want to host and consume RESTful web services from/within different mobile devices. I cant use socket for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use ASIHTTPRequest for webservice on iPhone, it supports RESTful. Give it a try, I am sure you will like it.

Comment: I have used it but I don't think its fulfill my need. What I need is host and consume RESTful web services from/within mobile device

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out something like this:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

Or, implement your own HTTP server on iOS (I suppose).

It's definitely possible.