# Android - Create RESTful WebService - Host it on mobile

Tags: android, web-services, mobile, hosting

My question is how to create a web service on android device & host it on the mobile device.

I don't want to *access* an already created webservice deployed on a *server*; I want to *create* a webservice that returns json/xml & host it on *mobile*.

[RESTful Web Services Implementations in Mobile Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452670/restful-web-services-implementations-in-mobile-devices) says it's doable for Java-based mobile devices, so I think it can be done for Android too.

Comment: Am I hearing you right in that you want to HOST (run a server) a RESTful service, from your Android phone? Or are you wanting to consume a RESTful service from your phone?

Comment: I want to host webservice on mobile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one problem with your setup and mobile devices: mobile networks (wifi and 3g) mostly use [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which prevents inbound connections. This makes mobile devices inaccessible from the internet (inbound) while they can still initiate outbound connections. For this reason mobile devices mostly do not host servers.

Comment: That is what I was thinking - and why on earth would you want to host a RESTful service on your mobile device? Talk about a battery drainer.

Comment: Its becoming a new thing. Even Symbian OS has started this. No doubt it'll drain a lot of battery but it'll also help you in many ways like accessing your numbers without touching your cell, publishing your images/videos. It'll give you a whole new way of accessing your smartphone.

Comment: @Khan More like it'll give OTHERS a whole new way to access YOUR information :P

Comment: obviously security will be a key issue but nothing is safe :)

Comment: @Khan - it wont work for the reason I stated. Second, if you plan to share media then you still need some kind of central user mapping server, so why not use this server to share data. 3. Why have other people download media possibly hundreds of times from your phone (think about your mobile data bill) if you could only upload once. 4. I haven't seen any other app do it. Have you? 5. I don't consider Symbian on the forefront of mobile development. Should I?

Comment: There are more user of Symbian based cell phone compared to iOS (Worldwide). Anyways media sharing was just an example. I understood your point about NAT I'll let my client know about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make an Android service which pings a server ( a web-server) every 30 minutes or so simply send a bit from client to server and back to check the availability of request from another phone. This way you can upload media files to server and download them to your another device.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve the same problem and I am leaning towards https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd.

It is a tiny webserver without any REST or MVC functionality, thus you would have to write it yourself (MVC, content negotiation, etc).

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do so?