# Host webservice on Android

Tags: android, .net, web-services

I've only found tutorials to consume a web service with Android.
But what I want to do, is to host a web service on a Android phone and consume this web service with a .Net application.

Does someone know a good tutorial or something like this?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why?

Comment: look at my comment below the answer of rogcg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/), a webserver for android.

Also there are some resources for your question:

1. [RESTful Web Services Implementations in Mobile Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452670/restful-web-services-implementations-in-mobile-devices)
2. [Android - Create RESTful WebService - Host it on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223323/android-create-restful-webservice-host-it-on-mobile)

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223369/399459):

> ...mobile networks (wifi and 3g) mostly use NAT, which prevents inbound connections. This makes mobile devices inaccessible from the internet (inbound) while they can still initiate outbound connections. For this reason mobile devices mostly do not host servers.

It could also drain your device's battery.

Hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Mhmm ok thanks. The task is to synch files from a PC to mobile devices. But in two ways (mobile device --> PC AND PC --> mobile device). 
This must be a part of my own app (no third parties App)
My idea was to realize this with a web service. 
But maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: Ok, but like rogcg writes it's a bad idea, perhaps with push message may be another way to do.