# How to expose webservice on specific port on Android mobile device

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to create an Android application that is running in background and when I'm entering, let say, `127.0.0.1:123456` on the mobile's web browser it returns some `json` file.

```
{
    "message": "Hello world!"
}
```

However in the classic backend programming it's the easiest possible task, in case of Android application it seems to be really complicated. I made some investigations and there're thousands of examples of **how to call webservice** but not **how to create one**.

I found the following topics:

- [RESTful Web Services Implementations in Mobile Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452670/restful-web-services-implementations-in-mobile-devices)
- [Android - Create RESTful WebService - Host it on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223323/android-create-restful-webservice-host-it-on-mobile)

But they're not really giving the explanation how to implement it and also not aligned with what I need - **I don't want to make it possible to call my endpoint from outside through the Internet** I just want to call it from the same device.

How to achieve it the easiest way?

---

What am I doing? I'm trying to provide my custom implementation of xDrip webservice so my Garmin applications are reading the mocked response instead of the webservice exposed by xDrip application. I expected it to be much easier!

Comment: 1) Have you searched for "github android webserver" on your favorite search engine. 2) If this is for a personal project you may want to look at [Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) to run a Linux like environment on Android device (Google Play store version is no longer supported).

Comment: I found something called i-Jetty but it was much much more than I need. Now I see there are many others implementations (e.g. https://github.com/sonuauti/Android-Web-Server) - I'll take a look! Thanks a lot! About emulating Linux environment - I really wanted it to be lightweight and android native

Comment: Update - ok, anyway it's not working :|